# Señalar página en la que me encuentro en el menu

Tags: jquery, css

Quiero que mi nav indique la página en la que estoy cambiando de color, el código Jquery que inserte es una "solución" que encontré pero solo se activa al hacer click (como indica el evento) y el resultado se elimina cuando se cambia de pestaña, cómo puedo hacer para que este efecto sea dinámico y para qu tampoco se borre cuando cambie de página?

```js
$('aside nav ul li').on('click', function(){
    $('aside nav ul li').removeClass('activo');
    $(this).addClass('activo');
});
```

```css
aside {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

aside nav {
  background: #1b7cd1;
  height: 100%;
}

aside nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

aside nav ul li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

aside nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.activo {
  background: #1560a1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="panel.php">Vista General</a></li>
            <li><a href="inventario.php">Inventario</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Cuenta de Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="../controller/terminar.php">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: Checa si esto te sirve: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `jQuery` puedes utilizar `$(location)` para obtener `path` y compararlo con el `href` de los elementos del menú, en caso de coincidir se añade la clase `activo`.

Debes tener en cuenta que si usas rutas relativas con carpetas o sin `slash` tendrás que adaptar el comparador del `if` para que sean iguales. En el ejemplo el elemento prueba correspondería al elemento reconocido en este `snippet`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var path = $(location).attr('pathname');
   console.log( path );
   $(".menu-elem").each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).attr("href"));
    if ( ("/" + $(this).attr("href")) == path) {    
      $(this).addClass('activo');
    }    
   });
});
```

```css
.activo {background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menu-elem" href="url1">Vista General</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-elem" href="url2">Inventario</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-elem" href="url3">Cuenta de Admin</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-elem" href="js">Prueba</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-elem" href="url4">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
```